# Why is the term "action only" called "action only"?

Tags: terminology

This is the definition of *action only* from Pokernews.com:

> In many card rooms, with respect to an all-in bet, only a full bet is considered a legitimate wager, in terms of whether this constitutes a raise that can be re-raised. Anything less than a full bet is considered to be action only, that is, other players can call such a bet but not raise it. For example, Chloe bets $10. Henry calls. John goes all in for $14. When the bet gets back to Chloe, she is permitted only to call the extra $4; the same goes for John.

What I'm confused about is why it's called *action only*? Because according to the glossaries I've looked up, *action* means the betting within a poker hand and if I'm correct, this consists of a bet, a call, and a raise; but if I'm incorrect and that *action* is only limited to a bet, this still does not make sense to me considering the example given indicates that one is only permitted to call, so why call *action only*, why not *call only*? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best explanation I [found was](http://www.poker-vibe.com/poker/terms/):

> **Action Only** - An all-in wager which is not large enough to re-open the
>   betting for someone who has already acted is referred to as action
>   only (as opposed to a bet, which could be raised by someone who has
>   already acted).

It's a little confusing. "Your Action" clearly states it's your turn to do *something* (bet, fold, raise, etc.). In this situation, your actions have been locked by the all-in. The All-in wasn't a raise, as the amount wasn't a legal raise, so instead we say it's "action only" and your choice is limited.